# Navigate through big image

Tags: codenameone

I have a big image with coordinate points.
I need to navigate through these points by pressing onscreen buttons.
Only a part of image is seen on the screen at once (shows your location).
By pressing arrow button the view moves to the next part of the same image.
[This example](http://www.jscraft.net/demo/plugins/craftmap/) looks good.

Please, suggest any way to implement this functionality in Codename One App

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Map component but you can place any image as a label icon within a scrollable container and just let the user use the touch/keys to scroll.